# Where's the error in the given bash script used to bubblesort?

Tags: bash, bubble-sort

```
array=( $(<abc.txt) )
len=${#array[*]}
i=0
while [ $i -lt "$len" ]
do
 j=0
 while [ $j -lt $(( (len - 1)) - i)) ]
 do
  k=$((j + 1))
  if [ "${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$k]}" ]
  then
   temp=${array[$j]}
   array[$j]=${array[$k]}
   array[$k]=$temp
  fi
 j=$k
 done
i=$((i + 1))
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

My array is not sorted and I also get a message ": integer expression expected". It works fine on my friend's computer. I just want to get an input from another file to an array and then use bubblesort. It also works fine if I declare the array as array=( 1 2 3 4 9 8 7 6 5 ).

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `sort` command?

Comment: You don't need to nest arithmetic expressions; `$(( (len -1) - i ))` is sufficient.

Comment: because as a student I was to implement the bubblesort algorithm

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net first.

Comment: Any teacher who requires you to write a sorting routine in `bash` is missing the point of shell scripting languages. They also don't understand shell very well if they are teaching you to use unquoted parameter expansions.

Comment: All good advice above. With a very small file, you could also run it with shell debugging/trace flags set and see where (and why) the error message is coming from. Add `set -vx` on the 2nd line of your script. Good luck.

Comment: So I tried spellcheck.net and except the "array=( $(<abc.txt) )", there isn't supposed to be any error

Comment: so, shelter's advice worked and I found out that I had forgotten about the \r at the end of my input file. How do I remove that?

Comment: `dos2unix file` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets didn't match in the second while statement and I changed
len declaration. chepner is correct, shellcheck.net would have solved this for you. (You can even install shellcheck locally.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#array=($(<abc.txt))
array=(1 2 3 4 9 8 7 6 5)
len=${#array[@]}
i=0
while [ $i -lt "$len" ]
do
 j=0
 while [ $j -lt "$(( ( len - 1 ) - i))" ]
 do
  k=$((j + 1))
  if [ "${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$k]}" ]
  then
   temp=${array[$j]}
   array[$j]=${array[$k]}
   array[$k]=$temp
  fi
 j=$k
 done
i=$((i + 1))
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: My file works fine when I input the numbers in the array just like you did but the problem arises when I input it from a file. A CR(\r) follows the last digit if I don't put a space after the last digit in my input file.

Comment: I've tried both with CR and without and it still works. Tested on debian8 linux with bash 4.4.12   does echo -n "${array[@]}" solve your problem?

Comment: For me, the CR does not allow the array to get sorted. I use Ubuntu 16.0.4 and when I used `set -vx`, in one of the lines was `+ '[' 9 -gt $'5\r' ']'
: integer expression expected
`.

Comment: $'5\r' is a string not an integer

Comment: Exactly. How do I remove the \r from the end of my file?

Comment: [ 7 -gt "$(echo $'5\r'|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')" ] && echo yes || echo no

Comment: I don't get it. Where do I use that in my code and how will it remove the \r from the end of any file?

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Comment: if [ "${array[$j]//[!0-9]/}" -gt "${array[$k]//[!0-9]/}" ] # after k=

Comment: How about removing the carriage returns when reading the file: `array=( $(tr -d '\r' <abc.txt) )`